# Removing the parentheses from within a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a function that ends up producing this:

```
exList=[([('Community Chest', 1), ('Jail', 1)], array([10, 17])), ([('Jail', 1), ('Chance', 1)], array([10, 22]))]
```

As you can see, it is a list and element i.e.

```
[('Community Chest', 1), ('Jail', 1)], array([10, 17])
```

within a tuple. 
I've tried removing all parentheses like this:

```
for element in exList:
    temp = ""
    for ch in element:
        if ch not in SYMBOLS:
            temp += ch

    results.append(temp)

print(results)
```

But it causes problems because the above code only works on a tuple, and not a list (I know, it's really confusing).

What I ultimately need, is to remove the outmost parentheses in order to get
this:

```
exList=[[('Community Chest', 1), ('Jail', 1)], array([10, 17]), [('Jail', 1), ('Chance', 1)], array([10, 22])]
```

As can you see, I want to remove the outermost parentheses.
Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: results is a list, array is what the module 'numpy' uses to define an array so it's irrelevant and SYMBOLS = '()', it was just where Python was going to go into to remove the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and the `itertools` module:

```
print [i for i in itertools.chain(*exList)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For you to remove the out side parentheses in:

```
exList=[([('Community Chest', 1), ('Jail', 1)], array([10, 17])), ([('Jail', 1), ('Chance', 1)], array([10, 22]))]
```

Simply name a new list and use numpy to make an array out of each element in the list:

```
newlist=np.array(lists[0])
```

And do so for every tuple within the list.